# SSIS - Disappearing External .dll

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm on a 2 developer team. We're running SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 SSIS. We have an external library that I've written to take advantage of some reusable functionality in a script task. I've signed the assembly with an .snk, compiled it, and added it to the GAC on the dev machine. When I load a project, I can add a reference to the assembly and use the code with no problem.

My peer can add the assembly and use the code, but when he saves/closes the script task and reopens it, the .dll reference is gone. We both have the reference set to Copy Local, and have confirmed that the .dll file is copied to the local project directory for me, but not for him. I've had him rebuild with the script window open This is a fresh VS 2008 install, so no user-specific options have been set as of yet.

EDIT: We're both working off of the same machine under different logins. He can view the file I've added to the GAC under his login.

Anyone have any ideas?

If I add the file to the GAC, he should be able to use it, right?

Comment: My guess is that you should add the file to the GAC on the other developer's machine, try it, then report the result back here.

Comment: It's a virtual machine (testing for now), and we're both running off of the same machine under different logins. If he views the files in the GAC, he can see the .dll that I have added.

Comment: @Mark: this, then answers that part of the question. Next part: look at differences between the logins; do a rebuild of all the projects on his login, etc. Also, locate and review the section of the Books Online documentation on using external assemblies in a script task. The requirements have changed in 2008, but I remember more requirements than just putting the assembly in the GAC.

Comment: We've followed all the steps outlined in this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136007.aspx. Everything still works for me, but not for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it -

The framework version on the script task didn't match the one from the assembly. I didn't know SSIS defaults the framework version to 2.0. Once we changed the framework version on the script task, everything worked beautifully.